# Why can't I download files from this server with wget?

Tags: linux, download, wget

I am trying to download several files from this server:

http://jaspar.genereg.net/html/DOWNLOAD/ARCHIVE/JASPAR2010/jaspar_CORE/non_redundant/all_species/FlatFileDir/

Essentially I want to get all the *.pfm files with wget but it just puts out an error message saying:

```
--2017-02-01 15:12:54--  http://jaspar.genereg.net/html/DOWNLOAD/ARCHIVE/JASPAR2010/jaspar_CORE/non_redundant/all_species/FlatFileDir/

    Connecting to jaspar.genereg.net (jaspar.genereg.net)|193.60.222.202|:80... connected.
    HTTP request sent, awaiting response... Read error (Connection reset by peer) in headers.
    Retrying.
```

I tried "normal" `wget` and `wget -r -A pfm`

I really haven no idea what the problem is.

When I specify the files directly:

```
wget http://jaspar.genereg.net/html/DOWNLOAD/ARCHIVE/JASPAR2010/jaspar_CORE/non_redundant/all_species/FlatFileDir/MA0001.1.pfm
```

It works fine.
Thanks in advance for any help you can offer !

Comment: You are aware that at most you would get the directory listing that way? Right? You could try to specify a different user agent, the server might be filtering the user agent.

Comment: Did you try `wget -d` to get more information on what's sent and received?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Switch useragent:

```
wget -r -l1 -U "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686 (x86_64)) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.75 Safari/537.36" http://jaspar.genereg.net/html/DOWNLOAD/ARCHIVE/JASPAR2010/jaspar_CORE/non_redundant/all_species/FlatFileDir/
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but can you please elaborate on why this works?